# Real-time Status Update on Client Android Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, tcp, socket.io

I'm trying to find the best way to send my users a real-time status update of a process that's running on my server - this process is broken up into five parts. Right now I'm just 'pulling' the status using an Ajax call every few seconds to a PHP file that connects to MySQL and reads the status, but as you can imagine, this is extremely hard on my database and doesn't work so well with users that don't have a strong internet connection.

So I'm looking for a solution that will 'push' data to my client. I have APE push-engine running on my server now, but I'm guessing Socket.IO is better for this? What if they're on 3G and they miss a status update?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess my answer may match what you need.

1st: You Have to Get **[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)** to run the **[socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)**

**BELOW IS SAMPLE CODE FOR SERVER:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8800);  //<---------Port Number

//If No Connection / Page Error
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

//If there is connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  //Set Varible
  var UserID;
  var Old_FieldContent = "";

  socket.on('userid', function (data) { 
    if(data.id){
      UserID = data.id;
      StartGetting_FileName(UserID)
    }
  });

  //Checking New Status
  function StartGetting_FileName(UserID){

    //Create Interval for continues checking from MYSQL database
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

      //clearInterval(myInterval);

      //MySQL Connection
      var mysql      = require('mysql');
      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        port     : '3306',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'ABCD1234',
        database : 'test',
      });

      //Setup SQL Query
      var SQL_Query = "SELECT FileName FROM status WHERE UserID = '"+UserID+"'";

      connection.connect();

      connection.query(SQL_Query, function(err, rows, fields) {

        //Do if old result is, different with new result.
        if(Old_FieldContent !== rows[0].FileName){
          if (err) throw err;

          //Display at Server Console
          console.log('------------------------------------------');
          console.log('');
          console.log('Fields: ', fields[0].name);
          console.log('Result: ', rows[0].FileName);
          console.log('');
          console.log('------------------------------------------');

          //Send Data To Client
          socket.emit('news', { FieldName: fields[0].name }); 
          socket.emit('news', { FieldContent: rows[0].FileName });

          //Reset Old Data Variable
          Old_FieldContent = rows[0].FileName;
        }
      });

      connection.end();
    }, 500 );
  }
});
```

**BELOW IS CLIENT HTML & JS:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>web sockets</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- URL PATH TO LOAD socket.io script -->
<script src="http://15.17.100.165:8800/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>


//Set Variable
var UserID = "U00001"; 
var socket = io.connect('http://15.17.100.165:8800');
var Field_Name = "No Data";
var Field_Content = "No Data";


// Add a disconnect listener
socket.on('connecting',function() {
    msgArea.innerHTML ='Connecting to client...';
    console.log('Connecting to client...');

    //Once Connected Send UserID to server 
    //for checking data inside MYSQL
    socket.emit('userid', { id: UserID });
});


// Get data that push from server
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    writeMessage(data);
});


// Add a disconnect listener
socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    msgArea.innerHTML ='The client has disconnected!';
    console.log('The client has disconnected!');
});


//Function to display message on webpage
function writeMessage(msg) {
    var msgArea = document.getElementById("msgArea");
    if (typeof msg == "object") {
        //  msgArea.innerHTML = msg.hello;
        if(msg.FieldName !== undefined){
            Field_Name = msg.FieldName;
        }  
        if(msg.FieldContent !== undefined){
            Field_Content = msg.FieldContent;
        }  

    }else {
        msgArea.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    msgArea.innerHTML = Field_Name +" = "+ Field_Content;
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msgArea">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for (: Does the above node.js send data to all clients connected on port 8800 or only to the connected client? Also, is there a way to execute a node.js file (that writes to a local socket maybe?) whenever i want to update the status instead of reading the status from the mysql database? Thanks!

Comment: **Does the above node.js send data to all clients connected on port 8800 or only to the connected client?**
Yes, for "Socket.emit", It send all data to all clients like broadcasting.

If you want it to send it individually you may try to apply this:
 
Node.JS - Server Script (*Not fully Test Yet)
"io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit('data', { FieldName: fields[0].name }); "

Comment: or

MySQL With Original Script (*Tested on MySQL - Server - Client)
"socket.emit('data', { FieldName: fields[0].name }); "

If the UserID from Client is set differently for every individual connection, it may not conflict other users. However, for security reason, apply "socket.id" as above on every send event should be a good practice.

Comment: **Also, is there a way to execute a node.js file**
I am Using a simple way to execute it which is creating a shortcut file and run it every time system start-up. Put This on target of the shortcut:     "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" server.js

Comment: **By Using "io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit" **
There is some Problem on SetTimeOut / Interval with "io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit" ... Due To if the season was disconnected & will cause error on Node.JS

Comment: Ok, I definitely need separate connections to receive separate data from the socket. I'm a little confused on how the code can manage many connections at once.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using *push notifications*, with the service provided for Android by Google as **C2DM**: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

You will need to implement a *PhoneGap* plugin to handle the native notifications, and communicate them to your *PhoneGap* project that will then (and only then) query your server .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not looking for a notification, I'm looking for more of a solution like Socket.IO open and recieve the updates.

Comment: It just seems like a little too much for what I need. The 5 step process should take a total of about 1 minute and the user is required to stay inside the app on the loading screen while the loading screen shows which step the app is on. Understand what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

As K-ballo above points out, using a push notification plugin would be best.

Luckily, some good citizen on GitHub has done this already!

https://github.com/awysocki/C2DM-PhoneGap

Please note: the above C2DM plugin was built for PhoneGap v1.2, so if you are running a more up-to-date version you will have to tweak the native code a bit to get it working better.